# Event anonymous function parameters not working correctly

Tags: c#

```
PictureBox[,] picBoard = new PictureBox[3, 3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        picBoard[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        picBoard[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(
          (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " + j.ToString()));
    }
```

I am trying to make picBoard[i, j] print the position it has in the 2D array when clicked. The problem is that each PictureBox prints "3 3" when clicked. This doesn't make any sense to me, since i and j are never equal to 3. I tried replacing i with 500 in Debug.Writeline(), and it performs as expected ( always prints "500 3" ).

Comment: It work "correctly" - as specified and as in 90% of the languages that have closures. It doesn't work as you (and quite a few other people, it's no shame) expect, but that's an entirely different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are captured by the anonymous method and once you leave the loop their value is 3. And when the callback is actually executed, well, their value is 3. To fix your code you need local variables to close over:

```
PictureBox[,] picBoard = new PictureBox[3, 3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    var x = i;
    var y = j;
    picBoard[i, j] = new PictureBox();
    picBoard[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(
      (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine(x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing over the loop variables, *their value* is only evaluated when the lambda executes at which point the loop has completed, that's why you see all 3's - make a local copy instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int localI = i;
        int localJ = j;
        picBoard[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        picBoard[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(
          (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine(localI.ToString() + " " + localJ.ToString()));
    }
```

As a reference read ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for why this happens.

Comment: The follow-up to that blog post is also very interesting, and should be read before complaining about this feature or devising a "better" version.

Comment: @delnan: Actually rumor has it that this might be addressed with C# 5

Comment: @BrokenGlass: We probably will change the *foreach* loop so that the loop variable is logically recreated every time through the loop.  "for" loops will not change.

Answer (score 1):

I love this problem!

That's because the event handler is a closure and it's capturing the value of i and j. That means that when the loop finishes, both i and j have a value of 3. So when you click, it shows 3,3.

To avoid this, you need to make a local copy of the variable with something like this (I don't know a lot about .net syntax)

```
var newI = i
var newJ = j
(sender, e) => {
   Debug.WriteLine(newI.ToString() + " " + newJ.ToString()));
}
```

This will make a copy of i an j with the correct values.